# ICalender Specification Confusion

Tags: date, calendar, icalendar

I am getting a confusion in the iCalendar specification mainly on [page 41](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-41), here is an extract of the place where I am getting the problem:

> The numeric value in a BYDAY rule part with the FREQ rule part set to
> YEARLY corresponds to an offset within the month when the BYMONTH rule
> part is present, and corresponds to an offset within the year when the
> BYWEEKNO or BYMONTH rule parts are present.

Further in the last line in the same paragraph, it says the following:

> the BYDAY rule part MUST NOT be specified with a numeric value with
> the FREQ rule part set to YEARLY when the BYWEEKNO rule part is
> specified.

From what I understand, a meaningless rule like `FREQ=YEARLY;BYWEEKNO=1,4,5;BYDAY=2MO;COUNT=10` is valid as per the first paragraph but invalid as per the second paragraph.

Is there another interpretation of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the `errata` of the `RFC5545` whose link is at the top of the RFC which you linked.

The [errata 3379](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5545&eid=3779) corrects the RFC by saying that RFC5545 Section 3.3.10

> [...] should say:
>
> represents the last Monday of the month.  The numeric value in a
>   BYDAY rule part with the FREQ rule part set to YEARLY corresponds
>   to an offset within the month when the BYMONTH rule part is
>   present, and corresponds to an offset within the year when the
>   BYMONTH rule part is **not** present.

(emphasis mine)